# Difference between vxworks 6.1 and 6.6

Tags: vxworks

Please let me know the difference between vxworks 6.1 and 6.6

Regards,
Sikandar

Answer (score 2):

Here are just some highlights:

- Posix conformance to PSE52 profile when using Real-Time Processes
- HRFS - new journaling file system
- new advanced network stack
- SMP Support
- support for new processors

Release notes would provide considerably more details